# Primary key and mapping of tables in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, entity-relationship

I am creating a spring boot application. I have tables as `Users (primary key userId)`, `Policy (primary key poliyId)`, `Requested Policies (For User)` and `Requested Policies (For Admin)`.
*Whenever a user request for policy the details should get added to requestedPolicies (For User) with userId and policyId as foreign key*.
**[Note : One user can request n number of policies so there will be one to many mapping]**
Now Admin can use `Requested Policies (For Admin)` table to approve/reject polices of user.

> I am a bit confused about how can I achieve this -
> Which key should I give as Primary key  in Requested Policies (For User) and Requested Policies (For Admin) as in Hibernate each table should have at least one primary key ?
> How can I give One to many or Many to one mapping according to my requirement ?

Please consider my ER diagrams as I am aware it is not appropriate !! Putting it up in post for readers to get clear idea about tables, will make changes later.

- tables shouls have at least one primary key and also mapping between tables is missing

Please suggest to achieve my requirement do I need to add any new tables and how can I map one table to another and what primary key should I give for each table ? Thanks In advance !!
[image: ER-Diagram]

Comment: check here please https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-primary-key-and-foreign-key/

Comment: actually got a probable solution for this. For catering my requirement I need to add one field in requested Policies table something as transactionID and mark it as primary key.